# mongoDB join between 2 collections

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to join two to collection.
First is a list of film :

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "movie:1",
    "actors": [
      {
        "_id": "artist:15",
        "role": "John Ferguson"
      },
      {
        "_id": "artist:16",
        "role": "Madeleine Elster"
      },
      {
        "_id": "artist:282",
        "role": null
      }
    ],
    "country": "DE",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:3"
    },
    "genre": "drama",
    "summary": "Scottie Ferguson, ancien inspecteur de police, est sujet au vertige depuis qu'il a vu mourir son collègue. Elster, son ami, le charge de surveiller sa femme, Madeleine, ayant des tendances suicidaires. Amoureux de la jeune femme Scottie ne remarque pas le piège qui se trame autour de lui et dont il va être la victime... ",
    "title": "Vertigo",
    "year": 1958
  },
  {
    "_id": "movie:2",
    "actors": [
      {
        "_id": "artist:5",
        "role": "Ripley"
      }
    ],
    "country": "USA",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:4"
    },
    "genre": "Science-fiction",
    "summary": "Près d'un vaisseau spatial échoué sur une lointaine planète, des Terriens en mission découvrent de bien étranges \"oeufs\". Ils en ramènent un à bord, ignorant qu'ils viennent d'introduire parmi eux un huitième passager particulièrement féroce et meurtrier. ",
    "title": "Alien",
    "year": 1979
  },
  {
    "_id": "movie:5",
    "actors": [
      {
        "_id": "artist:11",
        "role": "Sean Archer/Castor Troy"
      },
      {
        "_id": "artist:12",
        "role": "Castor Troy/Sean Archer"
      }
    ],
    "country": "USA",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:10"
    },
    "genre": "Action",
    "summary": "Directeur d'une unité anti-terroriste, Sean Archer recherche Castor Troy, un criminel responsable de la mort de son fils six ans plus tôt. Il parvient à l'arrêter mais apprend que Troy a caché une bombe au Palais des Congrès de Los Angeles. Seul le frère de Troy peut la désamorcer et, pour l'approcher, Archer se fait greffer le visage de Troy. ",
    "title": "Volte/Face",
    "year": 1997
  },
  {
    "_id": "movie:4",
    "actors": [],
    "country": "FR",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:9"
    },
    "genre": "drama",
    "summary": null,
    "title": "Sacrifice",
    "year": 1986
  },
  {
    "_id": "movie:3",
    "actors": [
      {
        "_id": "artist:109",
        "role": "Rose DeWitt Bukater"
      },
      {
        "_id": "artist:110",
        "role": "Jack Dawson"
      }
    ],
    "country": "USA",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:6"
    },
    "genre": "drama",
    "summary": "Conduite par Brock Lovett, une expédition américaine fouillant l'épave du Titanic remonte à la surface le croquis d'une femme nue. Alertée par les médias la dame en question, Rose DeWitt Bukater, aujourd'hui centenaire, rejoint les lieux du naufrage, d'où elle entreprend de conter le récit de son fascinant, étrange et tragique voyage... ",
    "title": "Titanic",
    "year": 1997
  },
 {
    "_id": "movie:19",
    "actors": [
      {
        "_id": "artist:44",
        "role": "Terminator"
      }
    ],
    "country": "USA",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:6"
    },
    "genre": "Science-fiction",
    "summary": "Deux creatures venues du futur debarquent sur terre. L'une d'entre elles, le Terminator, doit eliminer une certaine Sarah Connor, qui doit enfanter celui qui sera le chef d'un groupe de resistants. L'autre, Kyle Reese, est charge par les rebelles de defendre Sarah... ",
    "title": "Terminator",
    "year": 1984
  },
…
```

The second collection was composed by each artist (an artist could be an artist and/or a film director):

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "artist:1",
    "birth_date": "1971",
    "first_name": "Sofia",
    "last_name": "Coppola"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:2",
    "birth_date": null,
    "first_name": "Kirsten",
    "last_name": "Dunst"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:3",
    "birth_date": "1899",
    "first_name": "Alfred",
    "last_name": "Hitchcock"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:4",
    "birth_date": "1937",
    "first_name": "Ridley",
    "last_name": "Scott"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:5",
    "birth_date": "1949",
    "first_name": "Sigourney",
    "last_name": "Weaver"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:6",
    "birth_date": "1954",
    "first_name": "James",
    "last_name": "Cameron"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:7",
    "birth_date": "1973",
    "first_name": "Richard ",
    "last_name": "Fleischer"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:8",
    "birth_date": "1923",
    "first_name": "Charlton ",
    "last_name": "Hestone"
  },
  {
    "_id": "artist:9",
    "birth_date": "1932",
    "first_name": "Andrei",
    "last_name": "Tarkovski"
  },
```

I would like to know the film made by each director, something like that:

```
[{"first_name": "James", "last_name": "Cameron", "films": ["Titanic", "Terminator"]},
 …
]
```

I do the following request:

```js
db.artists.aggregate([
   {$lookup: {from: "jointure",
              localField: "artists._id",
               foreignField : "movies.director",
               as: "films"}
    },
    {$project: {"_id":0,
                "first_name": 1,
                "last_name": 1,
                "films.title" : 1}
    }
]);
```

and the result, not correct (I have all movies by director and not only film made by the director):

```js
{
    "films": [
      {
        "title": "Sacrifice"
      },
      {
        "title": "Alien"
      },
      {
        "title": "Titanic"
      },
      {
        "title": "Volte/Face"
      },
      {
        "title": "American Beauty"
      },
      {
        "title": "Sleepy Hollow"
      },
      {
        "title": "Vertigo"
      },
      {
        "title": "Piège de cristal"
      },
      {
        "title": "Impitoyable"
      },
      {
        "title": "58 minutes pour vivre"
      },
      {
        "title": "Van Gogh"
      },
      {
        "title": "Seven"
      },
      … 
   ],
    "first_name": "James",
    "last_name": "Cameron"
  },
```

Seems to have each director with all movies.

More:

I have a map/reduce solution but I'm not satisfied (and this is deprecated since 4.2):

```
var mapJoin = function() {
if (this._id.indexOf("artist") != -1) {
 this.type="artist";
 emit(this._id, this);
}
else {
 this.type="film";
 delete this.summary;
 delete this.actors;
 emit(this.director._id, this);
}
}

var reduceJoin = function(id, items) {
var director = null, films={result: []}
for (var idx = 0; idx < items.length; idx++) {
 if (items[idx].type=="artist") {
 director = items[idx];
 }
}
for (var idx = 0; idx < items.length; idx++) {
 if (items[idx].type=="film" && director != null) {
 items[idx].director = director;
 films.result.push (items[idx]);
 }
}
return films;
};

db.jointure.mapReduce(mapJoin, reduceJoin, {out: {"inline": 1}});
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the collection names in the local and foreign fields, `"_id"`, and `"director"` should suffice.

Comment: I try but I have the following result::


 {
    "films": [],
    "first_name": "Sofia",
    "last_name": "Coppola"
  },
  {
    "films": [],
    "first_name": "Kirsten",
    "last_name": "Dunst"
  },
  {
    "films": [],
    "first_name": "Alfred",
    "last_name": "Hitchcock"
  },

The film list was empty!

Comment: Ah I misready, those were not collection names.

Comment: That mapreduce looks like it expects movies, artists, and directors to all be in the same collection?

Comment: Say what you expect & why you expect it at the 1st subexpression in execution that you don't get the state you expect, with justification referencing the documentation or manual. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS This data isn't minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what 'jointure' is supposed to be.

If you have `actors` and `movies` collections with the documents you show in that example, a simple `$lookup` should suffice:

```
db.artists.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "movies",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "director._id",
      as: "films"
  }},
  {$project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "first_name": 1,
      "last_name": 1,
      "films.title": 1
  }}
])
```

If you only want artists with at least one film, add a `$match` stage at the end like

```
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {$size: "$films"},
          0
        ]
      }
  }}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W5NKTUUVAbR)